# ESP8266 ESP-01 not show data from server in Arduino IDE serial monitor

Tags: arduino, arduino-uno, arduino-esp8266

i am new in arduino and ESP8266 module AT commands. I still learn about how to receive data from server and it show the data in Arduino serial monitor. I will tell you how i do and i hope someone will tell me what's wrong with my code or if any mistake that i have done.

1. This is my php code in server side. Just a simple coding. I save it as index.php :

```
<?php
ECHO $_GET['subject'];
?>
```

2. This is my AT commands in Arduino IDE serial monitor.

```
AT+CIPSTART="TCP","nyalalampu.atwebpages.com",80

CONNECT

OK
AT+CIPSEND=110


OK
> CLOSED
```

After this > symbol appear i insert

```
GET nyalalampu.atwebpages.com/?subject=anis HTTP/1.0
```

After that i hit Enter button on keyboard.

I don't know why I don't see any data or text in serial monitor after i hit Enter button on keyboard. It's like nothing happen.After a few seconds what i can see just CLOSED message in Arduino IDE serial monitor. Why it don't print anis in Arduino IDE serial monitor just like i send in GET request to server?

I hope someone will show me somelight what mistake that i have done.TQ

Comment: remove the host from the path in GET. you already are connected to the server

Comment: @Juraj GET /?subject=anis HTTP/1.0 did you mean like this sir?

Comment: yes. is the length set in AT+CIPSEND exact? the AT firmware will wait fir so many characters. and the GET line must end whith \r\n which must be counted to the CIPSEND ength

Comment: @Juraj Sir...i'm really sorry sir...i'm still not understand about \r\n...can you give me some example ot AT command for my case?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol#Message_format

Comment: @Juraj Ok tq sir...